# Emacs: cocoa scroll-bar-mode can't turn off

Tags: emacs24

I have GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0, NS apple-appkit-1265.19) installed on my Mackbook Pro, although I have `(scroll-bar-mode nil)` in init file,but everytime emacs cocoa start ,it shows the scroll bar again, so confusing,any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `(scroll-bar-mode 0)` ?
That should hide them completely.

P.S.: I know I'm late ;)